# Can you force the window to appear where you set your default internet browser?

Tags: windows-10, browser, batch, vbscript

Is there any way you can trigger (from either the command line or some vbscript) the pop-up window to appear that allows you to select your default internet browser?

The pop-up I'm talking about is similar to the one below:

[image]

Closest I can get so far is calling `%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\System Tools\Default Apps.lnk` but that still requires two additional clicks.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

In the CMD prompt, in the *Run* dialog, or as a new shortcut, enter the following shell command.

> explorer shell:::{17CD9488-1228-4B2F-88CE-4298E93E0966}

This displays the *Default Programs* dialog.

[image: Default Programs dlg]

From there, click on *Set your default programs*.

[image: Set default browser]

Scroll down to *Web browser* to make changes.

Admittedly, this three-step process *should* be condensed to a single command, and if someone knows of a command-line option for *Default Programs* or another way to go directly to *Default apps*, please comment!

BTW, the default browser can be set silently through [Group Policy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/mdm/policy-csp-applicationdefaults) or [Deployment Image Servicing and Management (DISM)](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/8744-export-import-default-app-associations-new-users-windows.html).

Comment: Best I've managed so far is to launch `%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\System Tools\Default Apps.lnk` which is one less click than yours :)

Comment: @Richard, thanks, however that depends on the PC having that link (the one I'm at does not). Have you examined the properties of that link, to make this work generally?

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest you can get:

```
start ms-settings:defaultapps
```

More [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-settings-app).